# Spam bots are using .describe or /me to avoid getting timed out on Twich

Tags: mirc

Like the title says I'm having an issue when bots are using /me my script won't recognize the links they post.

```
on *:text:*kos.su*:#:{
  if (!$read(E:\Program Files (x86)\mIRC\op.txt,nw,* $+ $nick $+ *)) {
    .timermsg 1 1 msg # .timeout $nick 1
    msg # .timeout $nick 1
    msg # Sorry no links in chat $nick 
  }
}
```

Anyway I can get around this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you publish the `op.txt` file ? And also, what exactly you need the timers ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a different `on event` for actions. Have a look here: http://en.wikichip.org/wiki/mirc/on_events/on_action